# Wemos D1 mini not being shown when connected to macbook

Tags: esp8266, usb, ch340

I have multiple Wemos d1 mini lying around, but can't seem to get them connected to my macbook, to they do not show up in my /dev/tty?

I tried updating the driver, both using home-brew and installing the driver manually -  as suggested here

https://github.com/adrianmihalko/ch340g-ch34g-ch34x-mac-os-x-driver

but nothing seem to work? 
I tried different cables? no way to connect to it?

Comment: I finally had success following the **removal** instructions, but NOT installing anything.

Comment: @josecanuc, what removal instructions?

Comment: In the link you give in your question, steps 1-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the cables I tried don't have a data line

Comment: Oops! Well, that would definitely cause the problem! Glad you got them to connect.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/43369)

Comment: @MichelKeijzers - the answer is written by the author of the question - so it does answer the question

Comment: `I tried different cables?` seems like you have *multiple* power only cables, so technically, the answer should've been "All of the cables I tried don't have a data line"

Comment: @anita it would be great if you could expand on your answer making it clear for others who have the same problem. Perhaps you could add diagrams or tests to perform to determine if the data line is there.